# How to add HTML-like syntax around words containing certain letters in BASH?

Tags: bash

I need to add some custom syntax around certain words in a string. As a simple example, all words containing “A” or “B” should be individually surrounded by “`<red>`” and “`</red>`”, all words containing “H” or “F” should be surrounded by “`<blue>`” and “`</blue>`”, and other words are simply ignored. See this example string:

```
THE BEAR ATE THE FISH
```

This line becomes:

```
<blue>THE</blue> <red>BEAR</red> <red>ATE</red> <blue>THE</blue> <blue>FISH</blue>
```

- I already added spaces to the beginning and ending of the string, so any code can use spaces to easily distinguish words.
- If a word contains multiple matches, it can be marked twice, e.g. “`AFRICA`” becomes “`<blue><red>AFRICA</red></blue>`”.

How can I add this custom syntax around words containing certain letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an `awk` solution is allowed:

```
$ foo="THE BEAR ATE THE FISH AFRICA"
$ echo "${foo}" | awk '{
      gsub(/[^[:space:]]*(A|B)[^[:space:]]*/, "<red>&</red>");
      gsub(/[^[:space:]]*(H|F)[^[:space:]]*/, "<blue>&</blue>")
  }1'
<blue>THE</blue> <red>BEAR</red> <red>ATE</red> <blue>THE</blue> <blue>FISH</blue> <blue><red>AFRICA</red></blue>
```

This will maintain whitespace and does the `<blue><red></red></blue>` in case both match. If both are not requirements, go for the shell solution.

Comment: is this correct? i run this and got `<blue>THE</blue><red> BE</red>AR<red> AT</red>E <blue>THE</blue><blue> FI</blue><blue>SH<</blue>red> <blue>AF<</blue>/red>RICA` in GNU bash, version 4.2.37

Comment: I got this working `echo "THE BEAR ATE THE FISH" |awk 'gsub(/[^ ]*(B|A)[^ ]*/,"<red>&</red>") gsub(/[^ ]*(H|F)[^ ]*/,"<blue>&</blue>")'` it gave `<blue>THE</blue> <red>BEAR</red> <red>ATE</red> <blue>THE</blue> <blue>FISH</blue>`

Comment: @abasu See http://ideone.com/oezTyn. Are you sure the code wasn't mangled during copy'n'paste? What `awk` are you using (it's POSIX, so it "shouldn't" matter)?

Comment: Got the problem. Not a copy pest problem. `[:space]` did not work, `[ ]` worked. I have never used them, so did not face this till now,  and I am not sure why this is happening. Do you know why this problem came up?

Comment: @abasu `[[:space:]]` is not equivalent to `[ ]`. See [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.7) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes). If it didn't work for you, then your `awk` doesn't support POSIX character classes, hence my asking which implementation you are using.

Comment: mine is ubuntu and it comes with mawk which is not posix compliant. This caused the problem.

Comment: @abasu Funny. Just installed `mawk-1.3.4_p20100625` on my box and it works flawlessly, so it seems that the feature did get added a couple of years ago already. Weird that Ubuntu seems to ship with an older version then...which version do you have? Btw, google says Ubuntu also ships with `gawk` (it's just not the default, but installed in `/usr/bin/gawk`) and that you can change the default with `sudo update-alternatives -s awk /usr/bin/gawk`.

Comment: `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan` and it's ubuntu 12.10, fresh install. I checked just now, and gawk is not present. anyway, i'm getting gawk now :)

Answer (score 1):

### A POSIX shell solution

(will works with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) as well)

```
#!/bin/sh

x='THE BEAR ATE THE FISH IN AFRICA'

for i in $x; do
    case $i in
        *A*|*B*)
            case $i in
                *H*|*F*)
                    printf "<blue><red>$i</red></blue>"
                    ;;
                *)
                    printf "<red>$i</red>"
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
        *H*|*F*)
            printf "<blue>$i</blue>"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

### Output

```
<blue>THE</blue><red>BEAR</red><red>ATE</red><blue>THE</blue><blue>FISH</blue>
<blue><red>AFRICA</red></blue>
```

Comment: The default case should print the non-matched words, otherwise this will eat words not containing A/B/H/F.

Comment: The OP said : `other words are simply ignored`

Comment: Didn't see this :-) But I guess it depends on his definition of ignored, could be interpreted both ways.

Comment: Added specific treatment for AFRICA like words